# Bootstrap 4 Sidebar menu to stay open on page reload

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I integrated a menu based on https://www.codeply.com/go/T2mpwMOt60 into a website I'm building. Having used it during the build process there is one feature which I feel it misses.
Ideally I would like to have a menu item stay open when navigating to another page. So, looking at the sample menu, that would mean that if Item 3 was open, it should stay open when the page is reloaded, but close if another menu heading was clicked.
Given that every menu section starts with

```
<a href="#menu1"

<a href="#menu2"
```

etc, and when opened, the class changes from

```
class="list-group-item collapsed"
```

to

```
class="list-group-item"
```

I figured that the current menu state could be written to local storage and then read back in on page load to restore the previous state.

Does anyone know of examples that would point me in the right direction on coding this type of functionality?

I've just tried using the following script to save to localStorage

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('a').click(function() {
    //store the id of the collapsible element
    localStorage.setItem('collapseItem', $(this).attr('href'));
});

var collapseItem = localStorage.getItem('collapseItem'); 
if (collapseItem) {
   $(collapseItem).collapse('show')
}
})
```

It doesn't reopen the menu, but I suspect that is due to what is getting put into local.storage
As an example, When I first click to open the 'customers' sub menu, it stores  #menu5, which is the sub menu I would want to be reopened on reload, but when clicking any of the children inside that menu, the stored data will change to the url of the last clicked link.

Additional note, if I reload the page whilst #menu1, #menu2 etc is stored, then it loads with the menu displaying correctly. So it is purely a case of figuring out how to NOT store anything other than the initial #menu open.

Comment: **Method one:** use the sessionStorage() method to save a value saying whether or not a certain menu/panel was left open on reload, by saving true/false each time it is opened/closed. If needed you could also save some data about what was inputted, how far it was scrolled, etc. so it can act as a sort of restore point.  
  
**Method two:** Write a script that just grabs whatever you want to carry over and places it in the next loaded page.  
  
**Method three:** Use iFrames and stuff to seperate everything. That can cause a few problems but can be helpful for stuff like this.

Comment: @user9259829 I added some additional information about a script i tested, which is partially successful. Can you shed any light on it?

Comment: **Try adding a condition/comparison that makes sure it only sets the value if a menu was opened, rather than any object that is clicked.** Or set the Open button for the menu to something other than the a tag and use that instead. Maybe try **button**?

Comment: sorry for the excessive use of bold text, I always try to make things easier to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I used for this is below.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('a').click(function() {

    var menuNumber = $(this).attr('href').slice(0, -1);
    //console.log(menuNumber);
    if (menuNumber == '#menu') {
        localStorage.setItem('collapseItem', $(this).attr('href'));
    }

    var menuHome = $(this).attr('href').slice(-9, -4);
    //console.log(menuHome);
    if (menuHome == 'index') {        
        localStorage.setItem('collapseItem', '');
    }
});

var collapseItem = localStorage.getItem('collapseItem'); 
if (collapseItem) {
   $(collapseItem).collapse('show')
}

// Clear local storage on menu close action
$('#sidebar .list-group > div').on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
    localStorage.setItem('collapseItem', '');
})
})
```

I needed to be able to also clear localStorage if the Home link was clicked to prevent the menu from reopening on the last used submenu. 
Also added is a check to clear the localStorage data if the arrow icon on the menu was used to close it. 
Although it's unlikely that someone would close the accordion in this way and then refresh the page, I thought it better to be thorough.

Comment: Is 'url-hash'  is bound here?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the objects you are referencing in the event handler.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('a').click(function() {
    //store the id of the collapsible element
    localStorage.setItem('collapseItem', $(this).attr('href'));
});

var collapseItem = localStorage.getItem('collapseItem'); 
if (collapseItem) {
   $(collapseItem).collapse('show')
}
})
```

**On line 2**, it shows that the function will trigger if an *a* tag is clicked. Try using something else such as *button* and use that as the link that opens the menus, rather than using the same tag as the one for the hyperlinks. If you can't get that to work then maybe try adding something like an OnMouseDown attribute to each menu-opening button.

---

**Or try my current solution, which checks for a different attribute before saving. This is one that should work, as long as you give each menu-opening link the name here:**

```html
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('a').click(function() {
        if($(this).attr('name') == "menubtn"){
            //store the id of the collapsible element
            localStorage.setItem('collapseItem', $(this).attr('href'));
        };
    });

    var collapseItem = localStorage.getItem('collapseItem'); 
    if (collapseItem) {
       $(collapseItem).collapse('show')
    }
    })
    </script>
    
    
    <a href="#menu1" name="menubtn">Test 1</a>
    <a href="#menu2" name="menubtn">Test 2</a>
```

I wrote those modifications assuming that $ was already defined in your full project, if not then I'll leave it to you to work on that. Tell me if this works.

Comment: I'd already sat and figured out a way to resolve the issue, and a couple of others I experienced before I saw your answer. As I used the answer that I posted above that is really the accepted one, but I upvoted yours as I did test it and it achieved the goal laid out in the original question.

Comment: @Steph3071 That's great!  
  
I'd be happy to help again if needed